# Laurent expansion in the complex plane around $3<|z|<\infty$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, laurent-series, cauchy-integral-formula

I have the following formula and I would like to know its Laurents expansion in the complex plane with the condition $3<|z|<\infty$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Formula:  $f: \mathbb{C}\setminus\{-1,-3\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by

$$f(z)=\frac{z}{(z+1)(z+3)}
$$

This is what I tried:

$$f(z)=\frac{z}{(z+1)(z+3)}=\frac{-1}{2(1+z)}+ \frac{3}{2(z+3)}$$

If we just take a look at the first term, since the second term has an analogue calculation, we have the following:

$$k(z)=-\frac{1}{2(1+z)}= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} -\frac{z^n}{4\pi i} \int\frac{1}{m^{(n+1)}(1+m)}dm$$

The integrand has a pole with otder n+1 at m=0 and a pole at m=-1 with order 1. But since -1 is not contained in our domain, we can ignore this on. 
Now I should use again Cauchy Integral Formula, I guess? I do not how, since the order for my pole is n+1. So my problem is, is that I do not know how to compute this integral at $3<|z|< \infty$.

Comment: You are right! I did not now how to do it, so know I will edit it. :P

Comment: I did some extra edits, did I do it correctly?

Comment: Yes it is correct! :) @Arbuja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1}{z-a}= \frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-\frac{a}{z}}=\frac{1}{z} \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{z^n}\right)$$
when $|z| > |a|$.

Comment: This does only work for the term $\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{z+3}$. Thanks.
But what about the first term: $\frac{-1}{2}\frac{1}{1+z}$. Because I still have the condition |z|>3. And for this term I need the condition like |z|>1, which is not the case. :(

Comment: @esmo: if $|z|>3$, then $|z|>1$.

Comment: @mrf That moment when elementairy logic does not sound logical in my head. :')  Oops.. thanks!